# how to obtain $attr manually in angular

Tags: angularjs, attributes, directive

I want to know how I might manually obtain the attribute from the linkFn call back.

e.g. if I want scope, I do,

```
angular.element(element).scope()
```

controller

```
angular.element(element).controller('ngModel')
```

how about for attr.

Comment: The link function already has access to the element's scope as the first parameter to the linking function, so I'm not sure why you would need `angular.element(element).scope()`.  

How attributes are accessed depends on which type of scope your directive defines (no new scope, new scope, new isolate scope), and whether or not the attribute values contain {{}} or not.  Please provide an example of what you're trying to do.

Comment: I am wondering if it is possible to obtain the $attr outside of a directive placed on that element, in cases where I might want to act upon the parent and need to directly access or watch its child attr, without creating an extra directive just for that attr.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the parent controller I suppose you could access the attributes object after first assigning it to a scope property in the directive:

```html
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div my-directive attr1="one">see console log</div>
</div>
```

```js
app.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.attrs = attrs
        },
    }
});

function MyCtrl($scope, $timeout) {
    $timeout(function() {
        console.log($scope.attrs);
    }, 1000);
}
```

<kbd>[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/nFVPc/)</kbd>

Comment: u r missing my point here, I was wondering if its possible to find attr of sub elements with selector.attributes, you are solving the specific issue. but thanks for giving me info, I think what I want is near impossible

Comment: You should use the `scope` property of the directive definition to automatically bind to the scope the attributes you care about. 1) that's its purpose 2) the more you add to scope, the heavier the digest cycle becomes. No need to add all attrs if you only care about a select few. 3) you won't need `$timeout` because you'll have ironed out the execution order simply by using the `scope` property

Answer (score 1):

Use instances of the `$compile` and `$rootScope` services, call `$digest`, then access `attr` and `attributes`:

```
/* template string */
var html = "<div>ID: {{$id}}</div>";
/* template element creation */
var template = angular.element(html);
/* compile instance */
var compiler = angular.injector(["ng"]).get("$compile");
/* rootScope instance */ 
var scope = angular.injector(["ng"]).get("$rootScope");
/* template compilation */
var linker = compiler(template)(scope);
/* digest cycling */
scope.$digest();
/* scope linking */
var result = linker(scope)[0];
/* attr method */
linker.attr("class");
/* attribute property */
result.attributes;
```

**References**

- [NPM: Angular Node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-node)
- [AngularJS Source: injector.js](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/auto/injector.js)
- [Tao of Code: Studying the Angular injector - the twin injectors](http://taoofcode.net/studying-the-angular-injector-the-twin-injectors/)
- [The life and times of the angular provider](http://garabagne.io/2014/06/08/the-life-and-times-of-the-angular-provider/)
- [AngularJS API: $compile.directive.Attributes](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$compile.directive.Attributes)