# Call the link function of transcluded directive without ng-transclude

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Using transclusion on a directive along with ng-transclude in its template will call the link functions of possible nested-directive. E.g. having **item2** directive nested into **item1** (**[See Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/AIUKHgjpLrn5SLlDqUrl?p=preview)**):

```
  <item1>
    <item2>some text 1</item2>
    <item2>some text 2</item2>
    <item2>some text 3</item2>
  </item1>
```

With the two directives defined as

```
angular.module('someApp', [])

.directive('item1', function() {
    var linkFn = function(scope, element, attrs, nullCtrl, transcludeFn) {
      console.log('item1- linkFn');
    };

    var controllerFn = function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
        console.log('item1 - controllerFn');
        $scope.itemTab = [];
        this.addItem = function(item) {
            $scope.itemTab.push(item);
            console.log(item);
        };
    };

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        controller: controllerFn,
        link: linkFn,
        template: '<li ng-repeat="item in itemTab">{{item.text}}</li><p ng-transclude></p>'
    };
})

.directive('item2', function() {
    var linkFn = function(scope, element, attrs, item1Ctrl) {
        console.log('item2 - linkFn');
        item1Ctrl.addItem({ text: element.text() });
    };

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: '^item1',
        link: linkFn
    };
});
```

We have the following output

```
item1 - controllerFn
item2 - linkFn
Object {text: "some text 1"}
item2 - linkFn
Object {text: "some text 2"}
item2 - linkFn
Object {text: "some text 3"}
item1- linkFn
```

Because of `<p ng-transclude></p>`. Since I use `<li ng-repeat="item in itemTab">{{item.text}}</li>` to manually display, in some way, the content of the nested item2 directives, **I don't want to use ng-transclude**.

Then if I only remove `<p ng-transclude></p>` from the template

```
template: '<li ng-repeat="item in itemTab">{{item.text}}</li>'
```

.., the nested item2 directives link function are not anymore called and the output is

```
item1 - controllerFn
item1- linkFn
```

**How to call the link function of transcluded directive without ng-transclude?**

Comment: I am confused, which means it is more difficult to help. Try to explain what you want the output to be, and perhaps a working plunker or jsFiddle would be best, not a mock-up as the (see plunkr) resembles.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/8996/ I don't want to have the red text displayed. It is displayed because of the ng-transclude, which I need to use in order for the item2 link functions to be executed. Of course I could write ng-show="false" on it, but is there any better solutions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to obtain $attr manually in angular](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16697113/how-to-obtain-attr-manually-in-angular)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your Directive is **item1** is

```
    template: '<li ng-repeat="item in itemTab">{{item.text}}</li>'
```

will replace the child nodes.(since there is no **tansclusion**) so Your child directives **item2**

```
     `<item2>some text 3</item2>`
```

will not be parsed by the angular. So **item2** directive is not parsed.

And one more thing in your plunker code please add **ng-app** at the body of the markup.